# Error on npm start that dont happens in npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i'm a new dev. that was my first time trying nextJs. my code work as expect on npm run dev, but when i do npm start, there is only one function that crashes. that's a handleclick. In the console of browser, i can see its "blink" but nothing happens.
its an increase value of an context state.

that is de case on reducer:

```
case 'ADD_ONE_MORE':
  const getAllOtherItems = state.items.filter(
    (each) => each !== action.payload,
  );
  return {
    ...state,
    items: [
      ...getAllOtherItems,
      { ...action.payload, unit: action.payload.unit++ },
    ],
  };
```

the button code
OBS: that component is an styled-component component

```
            <CalcButton
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ONE_MORE', payload: each });
              }}
            >
              +
            </CalcButton>
```

someone knows what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you are running your old code.
Do `npm run build` and only then `npm run start`.

Comment: i did it, but still dont work